# How to use mix of jQuery and 3rd party JavaScript libraries in a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I am using visual force page to show the US States Map using "U.S. Map script, include both the jQuery and Raphaël libraries" - this is a third party library.

So once I add these libraries into static resources and calling the jquery and third party functions. But jquery function only called not the Raphael library. So how to add the code for calling Raphael library?

Here is the third part Library Link: [US states Map](http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-events). Here is the sample code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" id="page">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMap, 'USMapScripts/Scripts/jquery.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMap, 'USMapScripts/Scripts/jquery.usmap.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQueryMap, 'USMapScripts/Scripts/raphael.js')}"/>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    //var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
    j$= jQuery.noConflict();
    if(j$) {
     alert('jQuery Loaded'); 
    } else { 
    alert('jQuery Not Loaded'); 
    }
    j$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#map').usmap({});

    });
    $('#map').usmap({
        stateStyles: { fill: 'blue' }
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="map"  style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This got flagged by multiple users as being unclear... and I must admit I'm not sure what you're asking. Perhaps try again (I don't think you have enough rep to edit or comment).

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
$('#map').usmap({
    stateStyles: { fill: 'blue' }
});
```

is using $ when it should be using j$:

```
j$('#map').usmap({
    stateStyles: { fill: 'blue' }
});
```

because you have chosen to use j$ for your jQuery variable not $ which is often used and the default (but can cause conflicts with other JavaScript relying on $ having a specific value).

Your USMap library adds a function to jQuery called `usmap` that initialises the map. Based on the link you provided, Raphael is just used internally by USMap and you don't have to do anything yourself.

You will need to watch for errors reported in your browser's Javascript console if you are going to use JavaScript libraries.

Fyi, this works:

```
<apex:page>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JQuery)}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Raphael)}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.UsMap)}"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    j$('#map').usmap();
});
</script>

<div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"/>

</apex:page>
```

producing this output:

[image: UsMap in Salesforce]

Comment: hi Keith, I didn't get your point. can you elaborate your answer.

Comment: I got the below errors on my javascript console. a) Uncaught ReferenceError: Raphael is not defined
b) Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'usmap' 
c) Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'usmap'

Comment: Sounds like perhaps one or more of your includeScript references is wrong. But if you are going to use JavaScript you will have to invest some time in learning the relevant debugging techniques for it; finding someone you work with to give you some hands-on help and tips would speed that up.

Comment: can you have any debugging techniques pdf and any tips for these issue?

Comment: Yes, learn how to use your browser's "Developer Tools" as that is where all the code is executing. For this issue, the problem probably is that somehow the JavaScript files are not being correctly referenced; use the "Network" tab of your browser's "Developer Tools" to see loading errors.